# SUMIF formula with multiple ranges in filtered table

Tags: excel, excel-formula

The image below shows several rows in a ListObject table that is filtered on [Symbol] "MMP". I'm looking to sum the column [Qty] IF the column [Position]="LNG" AND the column [Is Closed]<> "DIV.

So in this example the correct answer is 1200 as shown by the yellow highlighted cells. The answer would be in a cell below the Table.

How can I do this with a formula?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that you want to do a Subtotal from a filtered table, I would suggest you to add a helper column to show the "visibility" of each row using the following formula:

```
=AGGREGATE(3,5,A2)
```

[image: Example]

Then use the following **SUMIFS** formula to find the subtotal:

```
=SUMIFS(Tbl_Name[Qty],Tbl_Name[Position],"LNG",Tbl_Name[Is Closed],"<>DIV",Tbl_Name[Visibility],">0")
```

The result would be the same if you actually filter your table using the given criteria and then use **SUBTOTAL** function to return the sum of the `Qty`:

[image: SUBTOTAL]